# Unrendered UIDL

Tags: java, vaadin

I develop on vaadin 6. I want to use the vaadin chart add on.

I've include all .jar files at web-inf -> lib and compile the widget set by vaadin plugin for eclipse. But this is the output.

```
Widgetset does not contain implementation for com.vaadin.addon.charts.Chart. Check its @ClientWidget mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to add-on instructions. Unrendered UIDL:

-Unrendered UIDL

-com.vaadin.addon.charts.Chart(NO CLIENT IMPLEMENTATION FOUND) id=PID10 height=300px width=400px confState={ "chart": { "type": "bar" }, "title": { "text": "Planets" }, "subtitle": { "text": "The bigger they are the harder they pull" }, "xAxis": { "categories": [ "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune" ], "title": { "text": "Planet" }, "axisIndex": 0 }, "yAxis": { "labels": { "step": 2, "_fn_formatter": "function() {return Math.floor(this.value/1000) + \u0027Mm\u0027;}" }, "title": { "text": "Diameter" }, "axisIndex": 0 }, "legend": { "enabled": false }, "series": [ { "data": [ 4900, 12100, 12800, 6800, 143000, 125000, 51100, 49500 ], "name": "Diameter", "visible": true } ], "exporting": { "enabled": false } }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Chris :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the new widgetset (built by the compiler) to be used.

Probably you forgot to specify it in your web.xml

https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin6/-/page/addons.compiling.html

Comment: okey i wrote in my web.xml: `<init-param>
   <description>Application widgetset</description>
   <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
   <param-value>com.example.test.TestApplication</param-value>
  </init-param>` but if i compile, this is the exception: Failed to load the widgetset:`/Test/VAADIN/widgetsets/com.example.test.TestApplication/com.example.test.TestApplication.nocache.js?1373817955849`